# Can’t find a switch in Cave 2

Tags: phantasy-star-online

(**Phantasy Star Online Episode I & II**, GameCube)

In most (or all?) map variants of **Cave 2** there is a barrier blocking the way to two brownish boxes. It’s in the corner of a room with a little lake and waterfall, if that helps. It’s a usual barrier where you have to find the corresponding switch, but I did not manage to find it.

It’s in the Cave 2 map of the quest **Secret Delivery**, too. I marked the spot in the [map (from PSO World)](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=799):

[image]

Is the switch hidden somewhere?

Comment: I've always wondered this as well. Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: @jmagnusson: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I found it. It's a step switch which is in the very same room, hidden under some bushes on the other side. [This is the map variation I had when I found it.](http://www.pso-world.com/sections.php?op=viewarticle&artid=493)